# (C) Minesweeper calculating function goes wrong

Tags: arrays, c, 2d, minesweeper

Hope your day going well. Thank you for visiting my post.
So I was trying to build minesweeper game, but got stuck at some problem.
Long story short, I have 2D array size 8*8. There are randomally 8 mines around the array.
I want to check: if at [row][col] there is no mine, whats the INT value it should hold.
I wrote a function that checks all the 8 options around the specific [row][col] I have.
For example:

```
if (game[row-1][col-1] == '*')
counter++
if (game[row][col+1] == '*')
counter++
```

and so on... 8 times. At the end, the function returns the counter value.
So I got stuck when I was trying to check, for example, row = 0 col = 7.
Because, row-1 gets me back to row[7], and col+1 gets me to col[0], and I don't want any of this to happen.
I've been sitting about 5 hours today, thinking of a way to fix this. But I couldn't think of any possibility rather than (approximately) 23 if's in one function.

Can anyone PLEASE hint me which steps I should take?
Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: `if (row > 0 && col > 0 && game[row-1][col-1] == '*') counter++;`

Comment: I need to check the [row][col] a few times, not just once. So the solution is just about 8 if's as you wrote? Each one for each check, of how many mines are near the specific points?

Comment: You asked for a hint. I gave you a hint. I assume that you can figure out the rest for yourself.

Comment: I got it. Alright. It's 11 pm here so I guess I'll try this hint tomorrow. Thank you! :)

Comment: @user3386109 so from 20 'if' lines, I got down to 16 lines. (Checking if row or col is zero, or maxRow, or maxCol, so it won't check the next spot). Is there any posibility doing it with something else than 16 if lines? The problem is when I'm trying to check the border of the board, then it will 'flood' and check [col] (which is 0, for example), then [col-1] (which is -1..). That's why I got to 16 if checks, my question is, is it even normal? Or is it possible to make the function smaller?